# Seeking pre-compiled QGIS to run from USB stick?

Tags: qgis, compile

Is there a place I can find pre-compiled QGIS?

I want to run it from my USB stick, without installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows you should look at [Portable GIS](https://www.osgeo.org/projects/portable-gis/) while on Linux (and I expect a Mac) you can run up a virtual machine based on the [OSGeoLive stack](https://www.osgeo.org/projects/osgeolive/).

Answer (score 0):

I run the windows version on my USB Flash drive also Network Share. I had to modify the batch file and copy some DLL's but then it works great.  The network share option is great it allowed me to offer QGIS to many staff that don't have permissions to install software on their machines.  I could also share Batch Files that use GDAL but use a network path for the executables.  I have it working with QGIS 2.18x I have not tried 3x as portable.